# regex code for allowing dot in windows forms

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have a code like this:

```
Dim builder As New System.Text.StringBuilder
                table.Rows.Cast(Of DataRow).ToList() _
                    .ForEach(Sub(row)
                                 builder.AppendLine(String.Join("|", _
                                 row.ItemArray.Select(Function(value) String.Format("{0}", Regex.Replace(value, "[^A-Za-z0-9\-\/\ ]", "")).Trim())))
                             End Sub)
```

but this regex removing my **dot(.)** value,i dont want to remove my dot values.becouse some price i am getting like (3.75,4.25),so how i can write code allow dot

Comment: Add the `.` character just before the `]`.

Comment: I guess you can use [`[^A-Za-z0-9-/\ .]|(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5eA-Za-z0-9-%2f%5c+.%5d%7c(%3f%3c!%5cd)%5c.(%3f!%5cd)&i=-i+am+getting+like+(3.75%2c4.25)%2cso+how+i+can+write+code+allow+dot.&r=). Does it work for you?

Comment: @npinti that code worked fine for me..thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to keep a dot in *specific context only*, you need to first add the dot to the negated character class and then add an alternative matching a dot if it is not enclosed with digits. If it is enclosed with digits, it should be removed/replaced.

Here is the regex:

```
[^A-Za-z0-9/ .-]|(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5eA-Za-z0-9%2f+.-%5d%7c(%3f%3c!%5cd)%5c.(%3f!%5cd)&i=-i+am+getting+like+(3.75%2c4.25)%2cso+how+i+can+write+code+allow+dot.&r=+)

Note that I moved the hyphen to the end of character class just as it is best practice (this way, you do not have to escape it), and there is no need to escape the space and a forward slash.